# sql query to output rows with one record and another query for those of more than one record

Tags: sql

I am working on two queries:

1. output rows with only ONE record based on `Barcode` FROM `Sputum_Collection`.
2. output rows with multiple records.

#### Sputum_Collection

```
Barcode | ID | SputumNo | Volume | Collect_Date
201003 | NCL37M | S1    | Yes   | 03/15/16
201003 | NCL37M | S3    |Yes    | 03/16/16
201002 | PCL75F | S1    | Yes   | 03/14/16
201001  |MCL29M | S1    |Yes    |03/14/16
201003  |NCL37M | S2    |Yes    |03/16/16
201004  |LKM23M | S1    |Yes    |03/16/16
```

#### Output for 1:

```
Barcode | ID | SputumNo | Volume | Collect_Date
201001  |MCL29M | S1    |Yes    |03/14/16
201004  |LKM23M | S1    |Yes    |03/16/16
```

#### Output for 2:

```
Barcode | ID | SputumNo | Volume | Collect_Date
201003 | NCL37M | S1    | Yes   | 03/15/16
201003 | NCL37M | S3    |Yes    | 03/16/16
201002 | PCL75F | S1    | Yes   | 03/14/16
201003  |NCL37M | S2    |Yes    |03/16/16
```

Comment: group by, count etc.

Comment: What is your question? Show us your queries and problem with them, so we will be able to help you

Comment: How is your work going?  Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a nested select to group your data based on barcode and use a `HAVING` statement to add conditions on the group.

**Query 1**

```
select * from Sputum_Collection
where Barcode in
(
select Barcode from Sputum_Collection
group by barcode
having count(*) = 1
)
```

**Query 2**

```
select * from Sputum_Collection
where Barcode in
(
select Barcode from Sputum_Collection
group by barcode
having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: I used these queries and it worked for me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For 1, Try this

```
select Barcode, ID, SputumNo, Volume, Collect_date
from
(
    select Barcode, ID, SputumNo, Volume, Collect_date,
           Count(Barcode) over(partition by Barcode) as Count
)
where Count = 1;
```

and for 2, you know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

**Query #1:**

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM 
    imt_database.test a 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         Barcode, COUNT(ID) as ct 
     FROM 
         imt_database.test 
     GROUP BY 
         id) tmp ON tmp.Barcode = a.Barcode 
WHERE 
    ct =1
```

**Query #2:**

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM 
    imt_database.test a 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         Barcode, COUNT(ID) as ct 
     FROM 
         imt_database.test 
     GROUP BY
         id) tmp ON tmp.Barcode = a.Barcode 
WHERE 
    ct > 1
```

Depending on your DBMS